# Replacing functions in composite function in haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I'm trying to become familiar with Haskell and I was wondering if the following was possible and if so, how?

Say I have a set of functions `{f,g,..}` for which I was to define a replacement function `{f',g',..}`. Now say I have a function `c` which uses these functions (and only these functions) inside itself e.g. `c x = g (f x)`. Is there a way to automatically define `c' x = g' (f' x)` without explicitly defining it?

EDIT: By a replacement function `f'` I mean some function that is conceptually relates to `f` by is altered in some arbitrary way. For example, if `f xs ys = (*) <$> xs <*> ys` then `f' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x * y):(f' xs ys)` etc.

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: What do you mean by "replacement function"?  Can you give a bit more of a concrete example?  However, I'm going to guess that the answer is probably "not without some refactoring".  If you could somehow make `f`, `g`, and co live under a single typeclass then you could rewrite all of your `c` functions to use that typeclass instead.  Alternatively, you can do explicit passing by creating a data type that has fields for each function you want to use.  There's probably also a template haskell solution possible, but I rarely suggest TH unless there really is no other way.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the typeclass approach? I presume I would have a typeclass with a function that takes the function and produces another function in the manner I want but how then do I use this to produce `c'`?

Comment: Maybe idea from 'Automatic differentiation' can help you.

Comment: @BenJacob Something like https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f5b44a138c346e2878aa7e88054a7311 might work (this is pseudocode), but each alternate implementation has to be similar enough.  It also has restrictions in that each function needs to use the `api` type somewhere.

Comment: You can't really do this without generalizing your function in some way (using type classes in some way, passing function arguments, etc). In order to direct you to what the best option is, we would need more information about what you're trying to accomplish. What problem are you working on (or, at the very least, what problem domain) and are there any constraints at all to how these functions can be altered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as seems to be the case with your example, `f` and `f'` have the same type etc., then you can easily pass them in as extra parameters. Like

```
cGen :: ([a] -> [a] -> [a]) -> (([a] -> [a]) -> b) -> [a] -> b
cGen f g x = g (f x)
```

...which BTW could also be written `cGen = (.)`...

If you want to group together specific “sets of functions”, you can do that with a “configuration type”

```
data CConfig a b = CConfig {
       f :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
     , g :: ([a] -> [a]) -> b
     }

cGen :: CConfig a b -> [a] -> b
cGen (CConfig f g) = f . g
```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise and reliable way to do something like this would be with `RecordWildCards`

```
data Replacer ... = R {f :: ..., g :: ...}

c R{..} x = g (f x)
```

Your set of functions now is now pulled from the local scope from the record, rather than a global definition, and can be swapped out for a different set of functions at your discretion.

The only way to get closer to what you want would to be to use Template Haskell to parse the source and modify it. Regular Haskell code simply cannot inspect a function in any way - that would violate referential transparency.